# Constructing new objects with validation in Java

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using Playframework with Java and I'm attempting to choose between a few  choices for creating valid User objects (which will then be persisted into the database in my business layer). Play uses [Forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms) as a way to help with validation.

So, inside my User class...

```
public User {
    @FooConstraint
    private String fooParam;

}
```

Option 1: Let the User constructor throw an exception

```
public User(String fooParam){
    Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);
    User user = new User(fooParam);
    userForm.fill(user);
    //Check if FooConstraint is violated
    if(userForm.hasErrors(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Option 2: Factory method that returns an optional

```
public static Optional<User> userFactory(String fooParam){
    Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);
    User user = new User(fooParam);
    userForm.fill(user);
    //Check if FooConstraint is violated
    if(userForm.hasErrors(){
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(user);
}
```

Option 3:
Let the business logic layer or controller layer do all the validation.

I appreciate any help with this.
Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question, but wouldn't this be more an SO topic  ?

Comment: True. This is probably more appropriate there.

Comment: Never used Optionals (I stopped Java around Java 7) but one big advantage of Option #1 is that _you are forced to deal with the problem_, 
(some might disagree if this is good) and , more importantly, you **get an explanation** if the Exception is informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is entirely dependant on the clients needs. You were trying to construct an object because you wanted to use it. Now, one way or another, it's not going to exist. That's a problem. What should be done about that?

You use optional when the correct response to the problem is to do nothing. Optional does nothing very well. Easier to read then null checks.

Exceptions are used when code needs to be executed to recover from the problem (so you catch and handle the exception) or recovery is impossible so you send an exception up that won't be caught and let the application die before it's invalid state causes it to corrupt persisted data.

And of course you can carefully check things before attempting to create anything and avoid the issue altogether. But how well this matches can be hit and miss so it's good to put some validation close to where it matters.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Users aren't persisted when you create a new User object.  So, I think I'm leaning towards Option 2 because there's no need to recover (no database exceptions and such). If I do Option 2, I could also make the constructor private. The Controller layer is then forced to check that the User passed to it from the client-side is correct.

Answer (score 3):

@CandiedOrange answer is fine, it depends whether you are o.k. with ignoring the error.  But, to elaborate, you should consider this question:

How rare or "**exceptional**" is it to get an invalid **fooParam**?

1. If you are reading from some "respected" database, REST endpoint, etc., bad inputs should be rare, and you should lean towards throwing an exception.
2. If this is user input, stuff you "scrape" from disorganized websites, etc., bad inputs will be more common and ignoring the "error" by using an Optional is quite reasonable.

In general, if you expect "garbage in", be more tolerant.  If you expect clean inputs, be stricter.

Comment: Or the way I like to think of it, the further away you are from a source of untrusted data (user input, file input, database with lots of applications putting data into it) the more likely it is that you should throw an exception. A good guideline is the diagram for Onion Architecture. The closer your code is to the middle, the more likely that exceptions are appropriate. The closer you are to the edges means bad input is more likely, so opt for a validation response instead.